# Creating function from choose statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following choose statement in my xml document

```
         <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="number($data)">
                     <xsl:value-of select="concat($data,$percentageSymbol)" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$data" />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
```

and the XML document header is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
```

How can I create a function which accepts 2 parameters and does the same logic as the xsl:choose statement?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0 then you cannot create your own function - unless your processor supports it via an extension. However, you can use a named template if your goal is to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you could write

```
<xsl:function name="f:do-it" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="percentageSymbol" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$data || $percentageSymbol[number($data)]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

(Are you sure you want `test='number($data)'`? That converts `$data` to a number and then tests whether the number is not zero and not NaN, which seems a slightly strange thing to do. If you're trying to test whether `$data` is numeric, then you've got it wrong.)

Comment: Yeah I am trying to test if it is numeric, any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of numeric? And what XSLT/XPath version are you using?

Comment: Any integer or double , Version 1.0

Comment: Then you want to test that `number($data)` is not NaN, which you can do as `string(number($data)) != 'NaN'`, or rather more obscurely as `number($data) = number($data)`.

Comment: Also one more question , it seems that the function namespace 'f' cannot be resolved because I get the follwing error : Prefix must resolve to a namespace: f . What do I have to do in order to recognize that namespace?

Comment: The namespace needs to appear in a namespace declaration, e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="...." xmlns:f="http://my.function.namespace/">` But if you're using `xsl:function` then you're using XSLT 2.0, in which case the best way to test for `$data` being numeric is to use `$data castable as xs:double`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're targeting [xslt-1.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0). If your XSLT processor
supports [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) (`xsltproc` does, among others) you can use
[`func:function`](https://exslt.github.io/func/index.html) and
`func:result`, for example:

```xsl
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
  xmlns:my="urn:so70882409:local"
  extension-element-prefixes="func"
  exclude-result-prefixes="my"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <func:function name="my:ownfunc">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:param name="suffix" select="'%'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string(number($data)) != 'NaN'">
        <func:result select="concat(format-number($data,'#0.00'),$suffix)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <func:result select="$data"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </func:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <out>
      <xsl:for-each select="*/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="my:ownfunc(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Sample run:

```shell
$ xsltproc --version | grep proc
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20910, libxslt 10134 and libexslt 820
$
$ printf '%s\n' '<v v1="12.345" v2="2022w05" v3="-.75" v4="1e3"/>' | xsltproc file.xsl -
<out>12.35%
2022w05
-0.75%
1000.00%
</out>
```